# Bash - Dialog msgbox piping into gauge

Tags: bash, dialog, pipe

On this code:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..50}; do
   #if [ ! $(jobs -rp | grep $pid) ]; then
      dialog --msgbox "Instance initilation failure!" 0 0

   #   return 1
   #fi

   sleep 1
   echo $((i * 2))
done | dialog --title "Initiating instance" --gauge "Please wait..." 10 60 0
```

The `dialog --msgbox` is being piped into the `gauge` and for this reason the gauge doesn't work and the msgbox doesn't appear.

Is it possible to avoid this to happen? To display the msgbox and then enter the `return`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just put the dialog call inside the loop.
I would suggest the following:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

for i in {1..5}; do
   #if [ ! $(jobs -rp | grep $pid) ]; then
        dialog --msgbox '"Instance initilation failure!"' 0 0

   #   return 1
   #fi
   (
        echo "$((i * 2))"
        sleep 1
   ) | dialog --title "Initiating instance" --gauge "Please wait..." 10 60 0
done
```